# What need to be kept in git of a cordova project?

Tags: cordova

I am using cordova for android development. There are a lot of code under `platforms/android` directory generated by `cordova add platform` command. I wonder what I should keep in `gitignore` file. I have searched that many people mention to ignore the platform directory completely. But I do need to adjust some source code in Java which is generated by cordova. I know I can put all source code `platforms/android/src` to git but I am looking for a best practise. I couldn't find one from cordova official document.

Comment: You can ignore the whole platforms folder, everything is built from config.xml and the www folder.

Comment: The problem is that I need to update some java source code under `src` in the platform.

Comment: The problem is that if you update native code it may be deleted when you use cordova cli. What I use to patch code from cordova libs is make a hook that will change the code before the app is built. If the code you want to patch is from a plugin, you can fork the plugin, like this you have your changes in a separate repo.

Comment: Place a hook is kind of risky since there are quite a few places need to be updated. Is there any other solutions for that case?

Comment: hooks are js code, so you can do anything you want. you can either copy .java files to overwrite original ones or opply a patch so it can work even if the original file is updated. But if you only target android and don't plan to use the CLI to upgrade cordova version, maybe the best for you is to put only the platflorm/android in git (and in that case keep all source files)?

Comment: I still need CLI to upgrade cordova version. So there is no solution to manage that? Basically I have to either setup a hook or create a plugin for that.

Comment: If you change cordova's java file and upgrade cordova, the files will be overwriten so either you try to rembember what you changed and change it again each time cordova deletes it or you can make a hook that does the changes automatically.